# Changing a Button's Content with another Button

Tags: wpf, button

With this code I managed to change its own content:

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Button button1 = sender as Button;
   button1.Content = "Something";
}
```

But how can I change it's content with another button?

I tried:

```
public void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Button1.Content = "Something2";
}
```

But this time I have to click the `Button1` first then the second to make it work.

Comment: What you are showing here should just work. Without seeing the relevant XAML parts we can't tell what's going on.

Comment: @Clemens Yes it's working but only if I press Button1 first. Without pressing Button1 before Button2, Button2 doesn't do anything.

Comment: Sure, you already wrote that in your question. But there is no obvious reason for that behaviour from what you are showing here. So show us your XAML...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I guess at your markup, it just works for me.

Because there's nothing inherently wrong in just that code.

This is an odd thing to do.

But it works.

Hence in MainWindow I have:

```
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Original" Name="Button1" Click="Button1_Click"/>
            <Button Content="Second" Name="Button2" Click="Button2_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    </Window>
```

And code behind:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button1 = sender as Button;
        button1.Content = "Something";
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button1.Content = "Something2";
    }
```

When I click Button2, the content of Button1 changes.

If it doesn't in your app then what difference is there in your markup?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made a new project and copy pasted the same code I've used before and it worked, so I don't really know what I had messed up but finally it's working.